# is there a way to process .NET/C# variables on external .js?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have my variable in an `aspx.cs` , such as :

```
protected string myVar="Hello";
```

Now, if I go to my `scripts.js` file added as :

```
<head>
    <script src="/scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

and I try this :

```
var myVarJs="<%=myVar&>";
```

it doesnt get the .NET `myVar` value.

Is there a way to catch it or am I dreaming?

Comment: I think you can mark the script as .aspx and then you should be able to.

Comment: There are ways that you can get ASP.Net to dynamically process .js files, however doing this sort of thing inside a .js file is a bad idea as it would probably break client side caching.  The answer that Ivan has posted is a much better solution.

Comment: I would like to see which is the best way to pass an Array to java script array ,maybe 2 dimensional String Array's .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Insert the variable before the script:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var myVarJs="<%=myVar%>"; </script>
    <script src="/scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to directly access C# variable in javascript code.
As C# is client side and Javscript is server side.

Unless on the Asp.net page you save the variable in a hidden field or label as text which is not visible.

Asp:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" value="<%=strvariable %>" />
```

Javascript:

```
function Button_Click()
{
    alert(document.getElementById('hidden').value); 
}
```

So this would get the hidden field with the ID of "hidden".

This could work I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can also register/render client script.  So you can declare variables in the backend and then render the javascript variables.

Comment: Check this ClientScriptManager out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager%28v=vs.80%29.aspx